# Cannot see Azure Integration feature in MaaS360

Tags: mobile, azure-active-directory, mdm, maas

I am trying to setup MaaS360 device compliance through Azure AD Conditional Access and having an issue with Azure Integration menu in MaaS360.
Basically one of the steps requires to setup "Device compliance status sync for Android and iOS" which requires the Azure tenant ID and Client ID established.

I am not able to see this checkbox when I go to the Setup->Azure Integration menu in MaaS360.

I only have 2 checkboxes that I allowed to configure:

- User Authentication
- User Visibility

I have been provided full admin roles on my account and I am not sure why else I cannot see this menu.

Here is the IBM article that I am following and if you see step 7 it shows the menu option.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/maas360?topic=iaam-integrating-maas360-microsoft-enforce-device-compliance-through-azure-ad-conditional-access

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please include what licenses you currently have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this, needed to enable this by opening a case with IBM to enable Azure conditional access.